# How to get an specific portion of script from a webpage in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, html-parsing

I am stuck in fetching some data from an html. I know I have to parse it but the problem I am struggling is that I don't know how to write the correct path (or even I don't know if it's possible) to get data from this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
  var chart = new charts.QuoteChart($("#container_quote_chart"),
                                              "EXITO",
                                              {"precision":2,"prev_close":33300.0,"data_values":[[1377253260000,33300.0],[1377253440000,33280.0],[1377254100000,33280.0],[1377255600000,33220.0],[1377257400000,33220.0],[1377261660000,33200.0],[1377264000000,33200.0],[1377264060000,33200.0],[1377267780000,33200.0],[1377271260000,33200.0],[1377273120000,33200.0],[1377273180000,33200.0],[1377273240000,33240.0]],"exch_open_time":1377250200000,"exch_close_time":1377273600000,"show_1D":true,"selectedPeriod":"1D"});
        new charts.AutoComplete(chart);
        });
    //]]>
</script>
```

The real data I need are the ones that start from **"pref_close"**  up to  **"exch_close_time**".

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: So you are asking how to pass those data from the script to Objective-C Native layer?

Comment: All I need is to get those pref_close and exch_close_time into two separate NSArrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks for the reply and suggestion but I managed to fetch the data I wanted by parsing it using the Hpple library. As for the XPath, which it was the real problem, I used a Safari extension named Firebug and it showed me the correct path.

What I did was opening the website page source; find the piece I wanna fetch; selected the row; right clicked with mouse and I have this "copy to XPath" option; pasted the code in Xcode.

That was it!!!